# How to create SSH dynamic forwarding through a port forwarding?

Tags: ssh

I can use the following command to create a port forwarding:

```
ssh -L 1081:192.168.0.2:22 admin@proxy.tunnel.com -p 22 -f -C -N
```

And then I can use the following command to create a dynamic forwarding:

```
ssh -D 1080 -f -C -q -N me@127.0.0.1 -p 1081
```

My question is, how do I combine these two commands and create a dynamic forwarding on port 1080 to `me@192.168.0.2:22` via `admin@proxy.tunnel.com:22` without first creating a port forwarding on 1081?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using `proxy.tunnel.com` only as a proxy.
Then you could use

```
ssh -D 1080 -f -C -q -N me@192.168.0.2 -o ProxyCommand="ssh admin@proxy.tunnel.com -W %h:%p"
```

With using `ProxyCommand` you can use the rest of ssh, as though you are on the proxy host.

But if the lines are getting long and complex it's easier to use `~/.ssh/config`

```
HOST myProxy
    user admin
    hostname proxy.tunnel.com

HOST myPrivateHost
    user me
    hostname 192.168.0.2
    ProxyCommand ssh myProxy -W %h:%p
```

Comment: This works! And ProxyCommand works with sshpass too. BTW add -p flag is the port is not 22.